# layoutinflator - can we inflate only a part of a layout

Tags: android

How can I use LayoutInflator to obtain only a part of a layout to be embedded in another layout instead of embedding the entire layout.

Suppose I have a layout named "`fromlayout`" which has two `TextViews` with id 'one' and 'two'
and another layout say "`tolayout`" to which I want to add only the `TextView` 'one' obtained from the other layout `fromlayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Inflate the whole `View` and call the `findViewById()` method on the inflater's result to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Think the best option to go for is using includes for more information have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(fromView);
View yourView = li.inflate(R.layout.to, null);

TextView tv = (TextView) yourView.findViewById(...);
```

Comment: The following is the code but it is not working public void doit(View v)
 {
  LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.top1);
  LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(this);
  View vv=li.inflate(R.layout.from,null);
  Button vt=(Button)vv.findViewById(R.id.b3);
  ll.addView(vt);
  
 }

Comment: i am trying to add code to my post but some error is coming regarding formatting .if you have any email i can send the code if required

Comment: on checking the logcat i found this error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: still awaiting any further response

Comment: I am able to solve the problem.By taking the parent of tv as in code above and casting it to ViewManager .from the viewmanager remove tv and then we can add tv to yourview.i hope it helps all.

Comment: @tejinder if your problem is solved, please mark the select this answer ! Thanks Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're attempting to solve a problem that you shouldn't have. If this `one` `TextView` is what you want in more than one layout, you can either instantiate it programmatically,  or you can place it in its own layout file and then include it in `fromLayout` and `toLayout` (or inflate it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewStub

In your FromLayout you can create one ViewStub.

```
<View android:id="@+id/One" 
...
/>
    <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub"
                   android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
                   android:layout="@layout/mySubTree"
                   android:layout_width="120dip"
                   android:layout_height="40dip" />
```

Now if you inflate fromLayout you will only get View One and to inflate ViewStub you need  to inflate it seperately.

If you require View 2 then you can inflate ViewStub like:

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.subTree);
View inflated = stub.inflate();
```